# web2py SQLFORM.grid url

Tags: grid, web2py

When I try to put form = SQLFORM.grid(db.mytable) in my controller the request changes to my/web/site/view?_signature=520af19b1095db04dda2f1b6cbea3a03c3551e13 which causes my if statement in controller to collapse. Can smbd please explain why this happens?

If I put user_signature=False then on view load the grid is shown (though the looks is awful, and I still need to find out how to change the view of my table), but on search,edit, etc. click, the same thing happens again. The url is changed and I get an error

Any suggestions?

thank you

EDIT

This is my edit function

```
@auth.requires_login()
def edit():
    #Load workers
     workers = db(db.worker.w_organisation == 10).select(db.worker.w_id_w, db.worker.w_organisation, db.worker.w_first_name, db.worker.w_last_name,db.worker.w_nick_name,db.worker.w_email,db.worker.w_status,db.worker.w_note).as_list()


#Define the query object. Here we are pulling all contacts having date of birth less than 18 Nov 1990
query = ((db.worker.w_organisation == 10) & (db.worker.w_status==db.status.s_id_s))

#Define the fields to show on grid. Note: (you need to specify id field in fields section in 1.99.2
fields = (db.worker.w_first_name, db.worker.w_last_name,db.worker.w_nick_name,db.worker.w_email,db.status.s_code,db.worker.w_note)

#Define headers as tuples/dictionaries
headers = { 'worker.w_first_name' :   'Ime',
       'worker.w_last_name' : 'Priimek',
       'worker.w_nick_name' : 'Vzdevek',
       'worker.w_email' : 'E-posta',
       'status.s_code': 'Status',
       'worker.w_note' : 'Komentar' }

#Let's specify a default sort order on date_of_birth column in grid
default_sort_order=[db.worker.w_last_name]

#Creating the grid object
form = SQLFORM.grid(query=query, fields=fields, headers=headers,searchable=True, orderby=default_sort_order,create=True, \
                deletable=True, editable=True, maxtextlength=64, paginate=25,user_signature=False
                )

form = SQLFORM.grid(db.worker,user_signature=False)


workersDb = db((db.worker.w_organisation == 10) & (db.worker.w_status==db.status.s_id_s)).select(db.worker.w_id_w, \
                                                db.worker.w_organisation, db.worker.w_first_name, \
                                                db.worker.w_last_name,db.worker.w_nick_name,db.worker.w_email,\
                                                db.status.s_code,db.worker.w_note).as_list()

workersList = []


for rec in workersDb:
    status =  rec['status']['s_code']
    workers = rec['worker']

    if not rec["worker"]["w_first_name"]:
        polno_ime = rec["worker"]["w_last_name"]
    elif not rec["worker"]["w_last_name"]:
        polno_ime = rec["worker"]["w_first_name"]
    else:
        polno_ime = rec["worker"]["w_first_name"] + " " + rec["worker"]["w_last_name"] 
    rec["worker"]['w_full_name'] = polno_ime
    rec["worker"]["w_status"] = status
    data = rec["worker"]
    #print rec
    #print data
    workersList.append(rec["worker"])

# If type of arg is int, we know that user wants to edit a script with an id of the argument
if(request.args[0].isdigit()):
    script = db(getDbScript(request.args[0])).select(db.script.sc_lls, db.script.sc_name, db.script.id, db.script.sc_menu_data).first()
    formData = str(script["sc_menu_data"])
    #form = SQLFORM.grid(db.auth_user)
    #print formData
    # If we dont get any results that means that user is not giving proper request and we show him error
    #print script
    #Parsing script to be inserted into view

    if not script:      
        return error(0)
    return dict(newScript = False, script = script, formData = formData, workers = workersList, form = form)
# If the argument is new we prepare page for new script
elif request.args[0] == 'new':
    scripts = db((auth.user.organization == db.script.sc_organization)).select(db.script.sc_name, db.script.id, workers = workersList, form = form)

    return dict(newScript = True, scripts = scripts, workers = workersList, form = form)
# Else error
else:
    return error(0)
```

also not to mention the sqlgrid looks awful, here is link to the picture https://plus.google.com/103827646559093653557/posts/Bci4PCG4BQQ

Comment: Perhaps if you show your `if` statement, we can figure out how to correct it. The signature is there for security purposes so the URLs cannot be manipulated.

Comment: Please clarify what you expect and what is happening instead (e.g., are you getting an exception?). Your `if` statement checks the value of request.args[0], so the user signature will have no affect (as it is stored in request.get_vars). Also, the URL would not look like my/web/site/view?_signature=... Instead, it would be something like /yourapp/default/edit/view/worker/1?_signature=... (Finally, please add line breaks to your code above so we don't have to scroll horizontally.)

Comment: Also, why do you apply the `.as_list` method to your `Rows` objects rather than using the normal `Rows` functionality to access records and fields?

Comment: Regarding the look of the grid, are you using the scaffolding application with the default CSS, and can you confirm that the CSS files are loaded on that page? If not, you will need to apply your own CSS styling.